# How to handle RecyclerView bind synchronous behavior when fetching data

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-recyclerview

I´m a bit new to this and I have this `RecyclerView` and I wonder how this will work even do it appear to work at first. 
My goal here is to make all View Holders use the same Static method to get data for population the View Holder. I notice It got really expansive to have each View Holder having there own data retrieval code

I have this `RecyclerView` and when calling the `onBindViewHolder` like:

```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(SearchPlaceViewHolder holder, int position) {
       holder.bind(mList.get(position));
   }
```

In the Adapter I have this static class like;

```
final static Helper helper = new Helper();
```

In the View Holder bind I call this Static class like:

```
helper.getSomeStuff(data, listener);
```

code:

```
void getSomeStuff(final Data data, final listener){
    DocumentReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("SOME_COLLECTION")
                .document(data.);
        ref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    final DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {

                        listener.onResult(data, document));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Since the method firers away an asynchronous call I think maybe the `data` and `listener` is not the same when asynchronous return.
    It seems to work but I get a bad feeling since all calls to `onBindViewHolder` happens in same thread (main thread)
    so that threads all synchronous calls to `helper.getSomeStuff()` maybe overwrite data

Any ide?

Comment: Your data fetching shouldn't be initiated from the adapter. Your data should be downloaded from somewhere else. It should be transfered to the adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter.

Comment: Thanks you are correct. My data fetching doesn't happens in the adapter. What my question is about is to learn how this asynchronous stuff work